Gazebo takes too long to fetch database.config
i'm using container to run my ros2 project, and each time i created a new container, the gazebo takes for like 3min to launch, i only have one table model inside .world.
and so i captured the network traffic of gazebo, found that the //table/model.tar.gz is not requested at start up, but model config file(from //database.config), then //table/model.tar.gz.
And it's so weird that the requests are not run in parallel which make it takes about 3min to load all that model config.
How can i speed this up???

Found one solution.
i just download it directly from model.gazebosim.org and put it inside .gazebo:
RUN curl http://models.gazebosim.org//table/model.tar.gz -v --output /tmp/table_model.tar.gz \
  && mkdir -p /home/container_user/.gazebo/models \
  && tar -zxf /tmp/table_model.tar.gz -C /home/container_user/.gazebo/models

